# RedBean разрешить подчеркивание в названии таблицы

Tags: redbeanphp

Как можно разрешить работу с таблицами, в названии которых есть нижнее подчеркивание? Как правило, почти у всех фреймворках и cms имена таблиц имеют префикс, а вот RedBean не понимает, вернее не разрешает использование _.

Как обойти эту проверку?

Answer (score 0):

Странно что никто так и не ответил, но вопрос гуглится, поэтому для тех кто позже будет искать решение, то вот оно:
Пишем плагин для РБ

```
R::ext('xdispense', function($table_name){
return R::getRedBean()->dispense($table_name);
});
```

И потом создаем таблицу через xdispense

```
$note = R::xdispense('lead_notes');
```